# What are multiderivative numerical schemes?

Tags: numerical-methods

I've been desperately looking for a clear definition, but I have not found one. Why the name **multi**derivative? What does it refer to? What are the unknowns that are updated from time step to time step?

Comment: Could you give a text fragment or a link where you saw this word used? Is it higher order mixed derivatives, higher order derivatives in general, or something completely different?

Comment: https://www.uhasselt.be/Documents/CMAT/Preprints/2017/UP1702.pdf This is what I've found :)